# Finding gold in Don't Starve

Tags: dont-starve

I have tried several plays on survival, but I can never find gold to make a science machine.  Is there a trick to finding gold?

Comment: I've found that if I mess with the world generation settings, sometimes I can't find certain things in my worlds (gold included).  Are you perhaps changing any of the settings?

Comment: @agent86 I'm playing with default settings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gold is most easily mined from large boulders with gold veins visible on the side.

[image: Gold Rock]

It can be mined with a pickaxe. These rocks are most commonly found in Savannah and Rockyland biomes.

Other sources for gold include Graveyards, Caves (Earthquakes and Stalgmites), and trades with the Pig King.

Comment: gold can also be found on the ground near graveyards

Comment: I'm pretty sure MadMAxJr knows about the boulders. He was asking how to FIND gold, not how to mine it once it's found.

Comment: I'm surprised he didn't mention graveyards. Another way of postponing your need for gold somewhat is by playing as Wickerbottom, who doesn't need a science machine to build the tier-1 stuff. You can start making backpacks, spears, crock pots and meat racks right away.

Comment: Tips on where to actually find the gold are helpful, thanks folks!

Comment: Updated with some additional gold sources.

Comment: Now that I've found this question (just asked a similar one, and deleted it) I have to say, the answer doesn't provide much more information than the wiki. I've found lots of savannah and rockyland biomes without a single gold-veined rock to be found.